# ad-hoc proxy between remote machines using ssh

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

I want to bridge 2 ssh tunnels.

I can ssh to hosta.example.com and to hostb.example.com from my machine, myhost.example.com (there may be jump boxes firewalls, other stuff in between, but suffice to say this is defined in .ssh_config).

hosta cannot connect directly to hostb or vice versa. I am aware that using '-L' and '-R' I can create a tunnel over the ssh connection, but one end of the tunnel is always my local machine.

How can I join the tunnels such that hosta.example.com can connect to hostb.example.com via myhost.example.com ?

(I tried Google but all I found was a million web pages telling me how to to setup a single tunnel - not join 2).

Answer (score 1):

If you successfully establish a following connection from your local computer:

```
ssh -L 1234:localhost:5678 hostb.example.com
```

then any local process that connects to `localhost:1234` will reach whatever listens on hostb's `localhost:5678`.

And if you manage to execute this on your local computer:

```
ssh -R 9876:localhost:1234 hosta.example.com
```

then any process on hosta that connects to hosta's `localhost:9876` will reach your local `localhost:1234`.

But your local `localhost:1234` is exactly the local end of the first tunnel (`ssh -L …`); so now a connection from hosta to hosta's `localhost:9876` will ultimately reach whatever listens on hostb's `localhost:5678`. This is an example of a chain of two tunnels.